# Preview Google Sites posts in announcements

Tags: web, google-sites

I am designing a website using Google sites for the first time.  I am trying to create an announcement page where I will write blog posts as I intend my website to work like a blog. I was wondering if on the announcement page it is possible to make it only show the preview of each post instead of the whole post just like it appears in the new posts gadget.  I would use the gadget, except that it won't let me create new posts using the gadget it will only display posts from an existing announcement page.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried any closing links for images using the target attribute?

```
<a href="*" target="_blank"><img src="*"></a>
```

Using a thumbnail instead of the main image that would be clicked would offer a preview of the image and utilizes the URL of the page you are actually linking to.

You could also format the link as the following:

```
<a href="*" target="new"><img src="*"></a>
```